# Database backup with T-SQL script - Issue with Declare and Set Variables

Tags: sql-server, database, database-backup

Can someone tell me why I can't backup my database with the script below? I can run the script but it didn't create the backup.
I"m using SQL Server 2008

```
DECLARE @pathName NVARCHAR(512)
SET @pathName = 'C:\Backup\MyBackup.bak'

...

EXEC sp_add_jobstep
...
@command = 'BACKUP DATABASE MyBackup TO DISK = @pathName WITH INIT',
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187358%28v=sql.100%29.aspx?

It looks like you are trying to insert a local variable into a SQL Server Agent job.

Based on this section:

> [ @command= ] 'command'
>
> ```
> The commands to be executed by SQLServerAgent service through subsystem.
> ```
>
> command is nvarchar(max), with a default of NULL. SQL Server Agent provides token substitution that 
>   gives you the same flexibility that variables provide when you write software programs.

You may want to try using tokens instead of local variables. This article may be a good starting point for you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175575%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

As it points out, your solution will look *something like*:

```
@command = 'BACKUP DATABASE MyBackup TO DISK = $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE (@pathName)) WITH INIT'
```